# more efficient option for running tail command

Tags: unix, tail

I have a very big file with few hundreds million rows. I am trying to use tail command to see a part of my file but it takes so much time. is there any option to use to reduce the time of running?

Comment: how much time does it take to get the last 100 lines?

Comment: If you're running `tail <file>` and it's slow, It's not `tail`, its your OS or disk. If you're piping to tail, that's a different thing.